# Switching between equation mode and align mode makes part of the equation dissappear.

Tags: equations

If I have this equation in this form in equation mode

```
\begin{equation}
    |\varphi_p(t)-\varphi_p(t_0)|=|0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}t_3) 
     ...(k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}...-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}} t_3)...(k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}..| 
     \leq|k^\epsilon \tau_{2n+1}-k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}|/3^{n+1} + |k^{\epsilon+\tau_{2n+2}}  \tau_{2n+3} -k^{\epsilon+t_{2n+2}} t_{2n+3}|/3^{n+2}+...
     \leq(2/3^{n+1})(1+1/3+1/9+..)=1/3^n \to 0 
        \end{equation}
```

The above prints out the whole equation perfectly but over one line.

However if I try to split it over a couple of lines like this

```
\begin{align}
    & |\varphi_p(t)-\varphi_p(t_0)|=|0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}t_3) \\
    & ...(k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}...-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}} t_3)...(k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}..| \\
    & \leq|k^\epsilon \tau_{2n+1}-k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}|/3^{n+1} + |k^{\epsilon+\tau_{2n+2}} \\ &\tau_{2n+3} -k^{\epsilon+t_{2n+2}} t_{2n+3}|/3^{n+2}+...
     &\leq(2/3^{n+1})(1+1/3+1/9+..)=1/3^n \to 0 
        \end{align}
```

This part of the equation is missing from the output

```
\varphi_p(t)-\varphi_p(t_0)|=|0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}t_3) 
     ...(k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}...-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}}
```

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please always post a complete small document that shows the problem, although using `align` with every row starting `&` is incorrect markup, and `...` should be `\ldots` they are unlikely to make text disappear. That said I do not see any `{` matching  the closing braces here: `2}}`

Answer (score 4):

Do not ignore error messages!

Your equation example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    |\varphi_p(t)-\varphi_p(t_0)|=|0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}t_3) 
     ...(k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}...-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}} t_3)...(k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}..| 
     \leq|k^\epsilon \tau_{2n+1}-k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}|/3^{n+1} + |k^{\epsilon+\tau_{2n+2}}  \tau_{2n+3} -k^{\epsilon+t_{2n+2}} t_{2n+3}|/3^{n+2}+...
     \leq(2/3^{n+1})(1+1/3+1/9+..)=1/3^n \to 0 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.8 ....(k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}...-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}}
```

clearly showing the extra spurious close brace `t_2}}`  the fact that if you hit return (or use scrollmode) and so continue after the error message and that a pdf is made does not mean that the pdf is at all reasonable. tex just recovers from errors to allow syntax checking more of the file, it does not try to make any sensible output.

You get essentially the same error, for the same reason in `align` but the pdf happens to show less output in that case.

Note that if you do use `align` you should put the align before the `=` so they *align* If you do not want any alignment points use `gather` or `multline`.

But here with `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%\begin{equation}
%    |\varphi_p(t)-\varphi_p(t_0)|=|0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}t_3) 
%     ...(k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}...-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}} t_3)...(k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}..| 
%     \leq|k^\epsilon \tau_{2n+1}-k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}|/3^{n+1} + |k^{\epsilon+\tau_{2n+2}}  \tau_{2n+3} -k^{\epsilon+t_{2n+2}} t_{2n+3}|/3^{n+2}+...
%     \leq(2/3^{n+1})(1+1/3+1/9+..)=1/3^n \to 0 
%\end{equation}




\begin{align*}
    |\varphi_p(t)-\varphi_p(t_0)|&=|0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}t_3)
    \ldots (k^\epsilon\tau_{2n+1}\ldots-0_3.t_1(k^{t_2}) t_3)
\ldots(k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}\ldots| \\
     &\leq|k^\epsilon \tau_{2n+1}-k^\epsilon t_{2n+1}|/3^{n+1}\\
&\qquad + |k^{\epsilon+\tau_{2n+2}} \
\tau_{2n+3} -k^{\epsilon+t_{2n+2}} t_{2n+3}|/3^{n+2}+\cdots\\
     &\leq(2/3^{n+1})(1+1/3+1/9+\cdots)\\
&=1/3^n\\
& \to 0 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```